# flutterFlow: map on a firestore database and get a single field from all documents

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

[image]

I created a firestore database with a list of "products" documents. Every products document has a "general_products_infos" field, which contains a "prices" field, which contains a "balance" field. I want to sum all the balance field of all of my documents and print the totalBalance.

I did a database query and I pass the list of documents as a parameter of my custom function "sumTotalBalances", but it doesn't work and it says "The getter 'general_products_infos' isn't defined for the type 'ProductsRecord'. Try importing the library that defines 'general_products_infos', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'general_products_infos'."

The function is:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '/flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/uploaded_file.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/auth/firebase_auth/auth_util.dart';

double? sumTotalBalances(List<ProductsRecord>? productsList) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  if (productsList == null) {
    return null;
  }

  double totalBalance = 0.0;

  productsList.forEach((ProductsRecord product) {
    double singleBalance = product.general_products_infos.prices.balance;
    totalBalance += singleBalance;
  });

  return totalBalance;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: can you share the ProductsRecord class?

Comment: Hi, the ProductsRecord class contains the general_product_infos record and other less important records